# f(n) tends to infinity and $f(n)=O(g(n))$ then $\log{(f(n))}=O(\log{(g(n))})$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove that if $f(n)$ tends to infinity and $f(n)=O(g(n))$ then $\log{(f(n))}=O(\log{(g(n))})$. I tried to use the fact that $g(n)/f(n)  \geq 1/c$, and then it's limit is bigger than $0$, but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(n)\le Cg(n)$ and $f(n)\to+\infty$ then $g(n)\ge \frac 1Cf(n)\to+\infty$ (since $C>0$).

Now use that $\ln\nearrow$ so $\ln(f(n))\le\ln(Cg(n))=\ln(C)+\ln(g(n))$

But since $\ln(g(n))\to+\infty$ for $n$ large enough it is greater than $\ln(C)$.

Therefore $\ln(f(n))\le 2\ln(g(n))$.

---

Your path was not wrong; you can continue like this:

$\ln(\frac{g(n)}{f(n)})\ge \ln(\frac 1C)\iff \ln(g(n))-\ln(f(n))\ge -\ln(C)\ge -\frac 12\ln(f(n))$

Similarly invoking that $\ln(C)$ is smaller than $\frac 12\ln(f(n))$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: thank you very much first. but I don't get how you got that ln(f(n))<=2ln(g(n)) from the fact that ln(g(n))>ln(C)

Comment: Well you must be very tired, lol... $\ln(f(n))\le \ln(C)+ \ln(g(n))<\ln(g(n))+\ln(g(n))=2\ln(g(n))$

Comment: oh yes I see, thank you man!